# Reverse Geocoding does not return a post code

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to use HTML5 geolocation functionality with some google map APIs, for a mobile web app, as follows...

I have a MYSQL table that holds address records for properties including post code, but no coordinates. I am successfully using HTML5 Geolocation to get the current coordinates using this code...

```
<script>
window.onload = function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);

    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var latlng = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

...The DB table is large and I want to restrict the results of a query on post code, and so I need to do some kind of reverse geocoding to convert my current latlng into a post code to feed my query.

Using the corodinates returned in 'var latlng' testing at my home address, I have then tested this 'latlng' in the Reverse Geocoding sample in google dev examples here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse but it only returns 'town, country' and no post code. Is there a way for me to get the post code every time, or perhaps find the nearest post code?

I then want to create my SQL e.g. "SELECT * FROM tblProperties WHERE tblProperties.postCode = 'geocodingPostalCode';"

I have tested the google dev example using other random coordinates that do return full addresses including post code but not at my home address, I need it to work all the time.

Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you are using for reverse geocoding uses the second result, which may be to broad for a postcode.  You won't necessarily always get a postcode, but the first result (results[0], rather than results[1]) would be more likely to have a postcode.